# UITableViewCell reorder element overlaying detail text label in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Prior to iOS7, the reorder icon would move the cell's detail text UILabel to the left and allow space for the reorder icon.  Now the reorder icon overlays the detail text.  Does anyone know how to stop this behavior?

[image: Before iOS7]

[image: iOS7]

Comment: Explain your question properly with some screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is also the same as [iOS7 UITableViewCell reorder control overlap detailTextLabel with UITableViewCellStyleValue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115167/ios7-uitableviewcell-reorder-control-overlap-detailtextlabel-with-uitableviewcel)

I've found the same problem, and have yet to find a nice solution. I did notice, though, that this only seems to be a problem if the TableView style is 'grouped'. If you change the style to 'plain' the TableView shifts the cells content in from the right as you'd expect.

So, depending on your particular needs, you might be able to change the table style.

Comment: Thanks John.  I now just test to see if iOS7 or greater and set style to UITableViewStylePlain